# Change of position after a rotation

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I rotate an object with `fabric.Image`. Then I draw a line to it but the line is drawn to the old top/left coordinates of the object. What should I do?

[image]

```
function rotate(event) {
var oldAngle = event.target.angle;

if (oldAngle === 0) {
    event.target.angle = oldAngle + 90;
}
else {
    event.target.angle = oldAngle - 90;
}
canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more code. Setup of canvas, drawing of the object, rotation and then the connection?

Comment: A complete setup on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?